# Name for the Study of Weapons, Guns, and Arms

Tags: terminology, british-english, science, generic-term, military

What's the term to name the study (or science) of weapons, arms, and guns?

I've come accross Ballistics, but it's limited and more *mechanical* term.

And Military Science might be broader term.

[Weaponology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weaponology) is a great word, but is too neologistic and sounds funny.

I'm looking for both historical and modern terms.

---

*Weaponry* might be the best choice for the that, though the term has plural connotation and indicates more the design and production rather than the study.

Comment: There is bound to be a term for this that is used in military schools.  You could try reviewing a few military school curricula, or perhaps find a discussion board somewhere for military stuff.  (There doesn't appear to be such a board associated with SE.)

Answer (score 1):

**hoplology** is the study of weapons.

> "hoplology" -  the study of weapons or armour.  [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hoplology)
>
> "hoplology" - The study of the methods, behaviour, and technology involved in human combat, **particularly weapons and armour**. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hoplology)

Comment: Thanks, but again, according to Wikipedia, [Hoplology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoplology) is a science that studies human *combative behavior and performance*. I think it'd be a bit more broader term with the stress on *fighting with weapons*.

Answer (score -3):

> Ballistics-the science of projectiles and firearms.

also

> the scientific study of the effects of being fired on a bullet, cartridge, or gun.